# Passing down content children via another ng-content?

Tags: angular

I build a drop down component that looks like that

```
<my-drop-down>
    <my-drop-down-element>First</my-drop-down-element>
    <my-drop-down-element>Second</my-drop-down-element>
</my-drop-down>
```

To make that work there is a `@ContentChildren(DropDownElementComponent)` in the DropDownComponent. That is working perfectly so far but now I have a bit of a strange request:

I need to wrap the drop-down component in another component, to handle some other stuff. What I tried is that:

**wrapper.component.html:**

```
<my-drop-down>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</my-drop-down>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<my-wrapper>
    <my-drop-down-element>First</my-drop-down-element>
    <my-drop-down-element>Second</my-drop-down-element>
</my-wrapper>
```

But unfortunately there aren't any content children in DropDownComponent if I handle it like that. I also tried `@ContentChildren(DropDownElementComponent, {descendants: true})`

Is there a way to pass down conten children via another ng-content like in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to wrap `drop-down`  you can do this :

```
<wrapper>
  <drop-down>
     <drop-down-el>first</drop-down-el>
     <drop-down-el>second</drop-down-el>
  </drop-down>
</wrapper>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phsygf)**

Comment: I though that's not possible at first but now I just pass an array of the input information for drop-down-element as an input to wrapper so I can *ngFor the elements. I thought it would be nicer to be able to do it in the template but I can live with that :)